# Uncheck values in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, checkbox

I have following checkbox

```
<td><?php echo  $this->Form->checkbox('purchase_owner_occupied', array('hiddenField' => false));?>Purchase owner occupied </td>
<td><?php echo  $this->Form->checkbox('purchase_an_investment_property', array('hiddenField' => false));?>Purchase an investment property </td>
<td><?php echo  $this->Form->checkbox('purchase_land', array('hiddenField' => false));?>Purchase Land </td>
```

When I check then then the post value is like below

```
[purchase_owner_occupied] => 1 
[purchase_an_investment_property] => 1 
[purchase_land] => 1
```

Let say I need to edit those information to uncheck purchase_land, when I uncheck `purchage_land` and check remaining 2 the post value will be as below

```
[purchase_owner_occupied] => 1 
[purchase_an_investment_property] => 1
```

I need to check all these value with extrastep code

```
if ($purchase_owner_occupied==1)  { // }
```

Isn't there are way so that unchecked field will have `0` value like below?

```
[purchase_owner_occupied] => 1 
[purchase_an_investment_property] => 1 
[purchase_land] => 0
```

Comment: can you rephrase `let say i need to edit those information to uncheck purchase_land , when i uncheck purchage_land and check remaining 2 the post value will be as below` ?

Comment: Can you tell us where you need this? Solutions may be different if you need that array key in controller or in model and when (beforeValidate, afterSave, etc). And can't you just modify that validation to be `if (isset($purchase_owner_occupied) && $purchase_owner_occupied==1)` to do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use different values ​​of **0/1** and also the `hiddenField` parameter is required:

```
<td><?php echo  $this->Form->checkbox('purchase_owner_occupied', array('value' => 'y', 'hiddenField' => 'n')); ?>Purchase owner occupied</td>
<td><?php echo  $this->Form->checkbox('purchase_an_investment_property', array('value' => 'y', 'hiddenField' => 'n')); ?>Purchase an investment property</td>
<td><?php echo  $this->Form->checkbox('purchase_land', array('value' => 'y', 'hiddenField' => 'n')); ?>Purchase Land</td>
```

Example output if I just select the second checkbox:

```
array(
        'purchase_owner_occupied' => 'n',
        'purchase_an_investment_property' => 'y',
        'purchase_land' => 'n'
    )
```